# VS2008 - How to enter debugging for *handled* exceptions?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

I'm using a class library (running in debug) in my app that is generating lots of `first chance exceptions`.  I'm assuming that these are being caught and handled properly by the class library , but I have no idea which part of the library is generating the messages, and since there are a lot of them I'd like to investigate what is going on.

So, is is possible to configure the debugger to break into step-through debug mode when any exception is thrown (whether or not it is caught)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Debug/Exceptions and check the "thrown" column if you want to break whenever an exception is thrown. You can either set it for all exceptions of a type, or per namespace, or per exception.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio, you can choose in the Debug menu, Exception and in the popup window set a check by thrown for the Common Language Runtime Exceptions.